# Disable End User Communication With PowerShell

Tags: api, powershell, office365

Back in November, Microsoft released a PSA informing 365 users about the end user communication features with manual instructions on how to disable it through the 365 admin portal.

```
Log into the Office 365 admin center
Click on Settings
Click on Services & Add-ins
Click on End User Communications
Flip toggle to Off as shown below.
```

We have over 200 tenants in our partner portal and would like to disable this via PowerShell with the Azure Management commands.

I have read the features of the Azure and the central management cmdletes and none of them at the moment seem to be able to achieve what I am looking for

There is no code at the moment other than a basic script to connect to the 365 API via PowerShell and connect to all the tenants with their IDs

Ideally, I'm looking to run this with a foreach loop across the tenants and disable this feature to stop the tips cluttering users inboxes.

Something like,

```
foreach ($tenant in $tenants)

{

 "disable end user communication" 

}
```

Does anyone have any input that may help?